# managed system.timer over un managed code

Tags: c++

New to the groups, sorry if this the wrong forum/etiquette. I am coding
a c++ application that requires the use of a timer-triggered event
handler. I decided to use the timer provided in System::Timers::Timer.
My understanding of the next part is not very good, as my code may
reveal, but as I understand it, my application is "unmanaged C++",
whereas the timer extension from the system DLL is managed. Therefore I
needed to use the gcroot template to allow the inclusion of the
"managed" timer code.

```
#include <vcclr.h>

#using <mscorlib.dll>
using namespace System;

#using <System.dll>
using namespace System::Timers;

class DataStream
{
   public:
   DataStream():m_N(48),m_saving(false)
   {
      // set up the window timer
      m_Timer = gcnew Timer;
      m_Timer->Elapsed += gcnew
      ElapsedEventHandler(DataStream::nextCandle);
      m_Timer->Interval= CANDLE_DURATION * 1000;
      m_Timer->AutoReset= true;
      m_Timer->Enabled=true;
    }; // default constructor

private:
   gcroot<Timer^> m_Timer; /* use gcroot because can't use managed object in unmanaged class. */

   void nextCandle(Object ^sender, ElapsedEventArgs ^e);

};

void DataStream::nextCandle(Object ^sender/*source*/, ElapsedEventArgs ^e/*e*/)
{
   // do some stuff ...
}
```

Here's the problem, upon compilation, I get this error:

```
Compiling...
dataStream.cpp
c:\blah\dataStream.h(18) : error C3867: 'DataStream::nextCandle':
function call missing argument list; use '&DataStream::nextCandle' to
create a pointer to member
c:\blah\dataStream.h(18) : error C3350:
'System::Timers::ElapsedEventHandler' : a delegate constructor expects
2 argument(s)
```

At first, I didn't include the & reference suggested by the compiler
because most examples I had seen do not use this.

Upon inclusion, changing:

```
m_Timer->Elapsed += gcnew ElapsedEventHandler(DataStream::nextCandle);
```

to....

```
m_Timer->Elapsed += gcnew ElapsedEventHandler(&DataStream::nextCandle);
```

I get the following error on compilation:

```
c:\blah\dataStream.h(18) : error C3364:
'System::Timers::ElapsedEventHandler' : invalid argument for delegate
constructor; delegate target needs to be a pointer to a member function
```

So I'm stuck at this point. I'm not sure if the solution is a few small
changes away from where I am, or if these errors are indicative of a
larger problem (i.e. me using the gcroot template and mixing managed
and unmanaged code with zero experience in that). I'm using Visual C++ Express Edition Beta.

Comment: Just a note, your code will look better if you format it with four spaces at the start of each line.  See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 4):

For VS2010 CLI/C++

The code presented is unmanaged C++.  If the Datastream class was managed it would be

```
class ref DataStream {...}
```

instead of the presented

```
class DataStream {...}
```

Also if the class was managed then

```
gcroot<Timer^> m_Timer;
```

would be

```
Timer^ m_Timer;
```

The nextCandle method needs to be static, or from a managed class.

A static nextCandle declaration would look like:

```
class DataStream {

private:
    gcroot<Timer^> m_Timer; /* use gcroot because can't use managed object in unmanaged class. */

    static void nextCandle(Object ^sender, ElapsedEventArgs ^e);

}
```

To add an EventHandler that uses a static nextCandle

```
m_Timer->Elapsed += gcnew ElapsedEventHandler(DataStream::nextCandle);
```

To add an EventHandler that uses a nextCandle method from a managed class

```
m_Timer->Elapsed += gcnew ElapsedEventHandler(this, &DataStream::nextCandle);
```

Good [example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx) under examples at the very bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Your nextCandle function needs to be static, or a stand alone function.  It's not an error due to mixing managed and unmanaged code, this is all managed code.

The problem is your member function passes a hidden *this* parameter, which is rarely the function prototype expected.